# Unable to insert string into database

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a json that looks like this:

```json
{
  first_name: "ammaam",
  last_name: "mamamama",
  birth_date: "1950-1-3",
  birth_date_in_string: "03 January 1950",
  email_address: "aryalmukesh60m@gmail.com",
  ...
}
```

And then, I have a post request in which I send the json to a php page.

Then I have the sql that looks like this:

```
UPDATE users SET user_json = {"first_name":"ammaam","last_name":"mamamama","birth_date":"1950-1-3","birth_date_in_string":"03 January 1950","email_address":"aryalmukesh60m@gmail.com","password":"827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b","profession":"amammamama","gender":"male","age":"68","bio":"mamamamamamammamamammamamamamammamamamamamammamamamamamamammamamamamamammamamamamammamamamamamamam","profile_picture":"..\/Images\/male_profile_picture.png","full_name":"ammaam mamamama","joined_date":"2018-04-21","joined_date_in_string":"21 April 2018","address":"","nickname":""} WHERE id = 23
```

All the connection related stuffs are fine and when I check the type of the variable using `gettype($variable)`, it shows string but I am unable to complete the query.

Can anybody spot the issue?

Comment: `user_json` is a JSON data type or what?

Comment: You need to put single quotes around the JSON.

Comment: But it would be better to use a prepared statement with parameters, it will take care of quoting and escaping for you.

Comment: @Barmar code???

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

The query generated should have user_json value as a string. The query should be

```
UPDATE users SET user_json = '{"first_name":"ammaam","last_name":"mamamama","birth_date":"1950-1-3","birth_date_in_string":"03 January 1950","email_address":"aryalmukesh60m@gmail.com","password":"827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b","profession":"amammamama","gender":"male","age":"68","bio":"mamamamamamammamamammamamamamammamamamamamammamamamamamamammamamamamamammamamamamammamamamamamamam","profile_picture":"..\/Images\/male_profile_picture.png","full_name":"ammaam mamamama","joined_date":"2018-04-21","joined_date_in_string":"21 April 2018","address":"","nickname":""}' WHERE id = 23
```

Spot the single quote (') in the query in my answer above

As suggested by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) in the comments above, its better to use Prepared Statements.

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp for help on Prepared statements in PHP.